# How to create a session#show when using Devise to create a Profile page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

first time poster so apologies if I come across very noob like.

I have started developing a TODO Rails app that allows people to login and create several lists for themselves.

I would like to have the user flow work so that after the user signs in they are presented with a "Profile page" that shows some importent links, info on the user and then a grid containing their lists etc.

Now down to the query, What is the best way to go about this as I have a User model and also a list model. Do I need to create a profile controller that has a simple #index action on it that I can pull in info from the 2 models or is there a more acceptable way?

I was hoping that Devise would provide something like this but if they do I cant find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I would couple my user profile page with Devise. Devise is a tool for user authentication, and it seems to me that a user profile page isn't really related to authentication.

I would put your user profile on the user show page, i.e. `app/views/user/show.html.erb`. (If it doesn't already exist, you might have to create a `UserController` and `app/views/user` directory.)

As for redirecting users to the profile page on login, this is (basically) how I do it in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    user_show_path(current_user)
  end
end
```

To address your last question, at least partially, no, I wouldn't create a profile controller. Thinking RESTfully, a user profile page would be most appropriate, it seems to me, in `UserController#show`.

Comment: Should I name the controller something different than User controller as I had set Devise to use the "User" word. Or is the point to extend the User controller from Devise?

Comment: No, I'd leave it as `UserController`. It's totally appropriate in my mind for Devise to share the `User` resource.